# Draw the histogram of the CDF of a Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to show that the histogram of the CDF of a Gaussian distribution is a uniform distribution. The Python code is as follows:
[image]
I try to translate the code into mathematica, but I have difficulty to draw the histogram(pdf) of the cdf of a distribution.

```
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], 10000];
Histogram[a]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dist=NormalDistribution[5,2];
xs=RandomVariate[dist,10000];
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[xs,50],
             Histogram[CDF[dist,xs],50]}]
```

[image]

Note: I simply translated the Python code. Of course the histogram on the right should not be misunderstood as an approximation of the CDF of a Gaussian distribution, which is [an error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_functions).

Comment: +1 "should not be misunderstood as the CDF of a Gaussian distribution".  Completely agree.  It is a histogram/count version of the probability density function treating the CDF as a random variable.

Answer (score 5):

@user293787 has provided the answer for your question so the following is just an extended comment.

You might consider ditching the histogram of such continuous distributions (especially because you have complete control over the sample size) for nonparametric density estimates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).  After all to compare distributions they need to be plotted as probability density functions rather than with bars of counts.

Here's how to do that in *Mathematica*:

```
dist = NormalDistribution[5, 2];
xs = RandomVariate[dist, 10000];
GraphicsRow[{SmoothHistogram[xs, Automatic, "PDF"],
  Plot[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[CDF[dist, xs], Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Gaussian"}], x],
   {x, -0.1, 1.1}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, Exclusions -> None]}]
```

[image: PDF of the two distributions]